# Update list in view for android

Tags: android, listview

So i have a UI with button which displays a popup user input when clicked. Whatever is input should be added to an arraylist and displayed in a list on screen. The following is my code. I have tried using notifyDataSetChanged() to update the view but to no results.

```
public class reminderList extends ListActivity
{
ArrayList values = new ArrayList(20);
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    values.add(0,"Test");
    values.add(0,"test2");

    //final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));

    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTask);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            alertPop();

        }
    });
}

private void alertPop() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter new task");
    alert.setMessage("Input");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Editable uin = input.getText();
            // Do something with value!
            values.add(0,uin);

            //((ArrayAdapter<Object>) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Place notifyDataSetChanged() just after setting the adapter....

eg:

`ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,` `values)`

`setListAdapter(adpt);`

`notifyDataSetChanged(adpt);`